# xarray and netCDF file with empty variables and 0-dimensional object dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, netcdf, python-xarray

I'm trying to convert some .nc files into `pandas` dataframes using `xarray`.

Here's one of the netCDF files:

ftp://l5ftl01.larc.nasa.gov/MISR/MIL2ASAE.003/2017.08.31/MISR_AM1_AS_AEROSOL_P006_O094165_F13_0023.nc

And the code:

```
import xarray as xr
ds = xr.open_dataset("MISR_AM1_AS_AEROSOL_P006_O094165_F13_0023.nc")
df = ds.to_dataframe()
```

And the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\abreucbr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\
dataset.py", line 3088, in to_dataframe
    return self._to_dataframe(self.dims)
  File "C:\Users\abreucbr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\
dataset.py", line 3078, in _to_dataframe
    index = self.coords.to_index(ordered_dims)
  File "C:\Users\abreucbr\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\xarray\core\
coordinates.py", line 80, in to_index
    raise ValueError('no valid index for a 0-dimensional object')
ValueError: no valid index for a 0-dimensional object
```

If I inspect the `ds` variable, for example,

```
ds.variables
```

I get

```
Frozen(OrderedDict())
```

The .nc file has a few MB, so it doesn't seem to be "empty".

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your dataset seems to be setup with a hierarchy of [groups](http://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/high/group.html). Xarray's [`open_dataset`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.open_dataset.html#xarray.open_dataset) function only supports opening a single group at a time. So you'll need to open just one group at a time. Something like:

```
xr.open_dataset("MISR_AM1_AS_AEROSOL_P006_O094165_F13_0023.nc", group='4.4_KM_PRODUCTS')
```

Generally speaking, the `to_dataframe` method is going to have limited utility for your dataset since collapsing 6 dimensions into a single index is going to be pretty clunky/inefficient.

Comment: Oh wow! Where did you find the information about `'4.4_KM_PRODUCTS'`?

Comment: Found it: https://eosweb.larc.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/project/misr/DPS_AEROSOL_V023.20180125.pdf

Comment: For example, `ncdump -h`, which tells you (among a lot of other things) `group: \4.4_KM_PRODUCTS`

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect the nc-file using netcdf4 Dataset. This gives you insight in the complete structure including groups.

Comment: Thanks! That can be done as follows: `nc = netCDF4.Dataset("file.nc")` and then `nc.groups`.